# Modern syntax vs old syntax for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, ecmascript-6

I have this code that is working successfully using modern syntax.

```
function maxChar(str) {
  const charMap = {}
  for(let char of str){
    charMap[char] = 1
  }

  return charMap
}

console.log(maxChar('acdef'))
```

It returns an object like this:

```
{a:1,c:1,d:1,e:1,f:1}
```

I wanted to do the same thing, but with the old syntax. I did it that way and it did not work.

```
function maxChar(str) {
  const charMap = {}
  for(let char=0; char < str.length; char++){
    charMap[char] = 1
  }

  return charMap
}

console.log(maxChar('acdef'))
```

It was returned this:

```
{0:1,1:1,2:1,3:1,4:1}
```

How do I return the same thing as the previous example?

The only difference between the two was that the former used the modern loop feature

Comment: In the first case, `char` is a string due to the `for.. of` behavior, since Strings are **iterables**. In the second case, `char` is a **number**, used as a **counter** in your for loop. You should get the `str` index using `char` instead: `const _char = str[char]; charMap[_char] = 1`. Read more about how **for.. of** works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set key as `str[char]`

- `str[char]` is the character of the `str` at the index `char`
- `char` is a variable which is number.

```js
function maxChar(str) {
  const charMap = {}
  for(let char=0; char < str.length; char++){
    charMap[str[char]] = 1
  }

  return charMap
}

console.log(maxChar('acdef'))
```

Comment: Maheer Ali do you know any app website that does this translation?  between new syntax to old syntax?

Comment: @claudiobitar tbh I don't but some people say about babel.(I don't know to work with it.)

Comment: Thank you i had listened about babel too. I will check out it.

Answer (score 2):

Because with `for...of` with a string, `char` is assigned the value `str[index]`. To do the same with the old syntax, use `charMap[str[char]]`:

```js
function maxChar(str) {
  const charMap = {}
  for (let char = 0; char < str.length; char++) {
    charMap[str[char]] = 1;
  }
  return charMap;
}

console.log(maxChar('acdef'));
```

You can also simplify the function:

```js
function maxChar(str) {
  const charMap = {};
  str.split("").forEach(function(char) {
    charMap[char] = 1;
  });
  return charMap;
}

console.log(maxChar('acdef'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `char` in your for loop is your loop counter, which is a number. To make it more readable I suggest renaming it as `i`, which is widely used with for loops.

With this counter, you can then access your character with `str[i]`:

```js
function maxChar(str) {
  const charMap = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    charMap[str[i]] = 1
  }
  return charMap
}

console.log(maxChar('acdef'))
```

You could also use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do it:

```js
const maxChar = str => [...str].reduce((map, x) => ({ ...map, [x]: 1 }), {})

console.log(maxChar('acdef'))
```